# Getting audio over bluetooth on PiZeroW

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w, phat-dac

I have a PiZeroW set up as a headless Spotify connect device. The OS is the latest Raspbian Stretch. I have the audio output connected through a Pimoroni PHAT DAC. The device is setup using instructions from [Raspotify](https://github.com/dtcooper/raspotify).

This setup works perfectly well with good connection and audio. I am now trying to extend the capability of this device to become a bluetooth connection for audio from other sources, I installed the bluetooth package that includes blueman bluetooth manager and pulse audio:

```
sudo apt-get install blueman pulseaudio pavucontrol pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

I am able to see the PiZeroW on my bluetooth devices and am able to connect the devices to the Pi and vice versa. From the VNC viewer I am able to see that the sound and audio control panel see the HiFiberry DAC as the input device and the output device but there is no audio being played.

```
pi@pizerow:~ $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sndrpihifiberry [snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac], device 0: HifiBerry DAC HiFi pcm5102a-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
pi@pizerow:~ $ 
pi@pizerow:~ $ aplay -L
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
sysdefault:CARD=sndrpihifiberry
    snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac, 
    Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=sndrpihifiberry,DEV=0
    snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=sndrpihifiberry,DEV=0
    snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac, 
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=sndrpihifiberry,DEV=0
    snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac, 
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=sndrpihifiberry,DEV=0
    snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac,
```

This is the output of the aplay -l / -L commands.

As I mentioned the device works well as a wireless Spotify dvice so I know the DAC is functioning and the output leads are properly soldered.